# Explanation as to why Male/Female Wizards have sexy bodies

Tags: society, magic, culture

I know that RPGs employ eye candy tactics to players of their preferred sex in order to entice the players into the game.

Male Wizards are sexy and muscular.
Female Wizards are sexy and have big boobs.

Aside from that, is there any other practical explanation why some wizards are so hot and sexy when most of their time is spent on studying rather than going to the gym?

Comment: Hello, *Meiji Marts*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  Please take our [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the way this site works.  Have a nice day!

Comment: Have you seen the scene in "Game of Thrones" in which (arguably sexy) Red Lady Melisandre is taking off her necklace?

Comment: Sorry no, I don't watch Game of Thrones, can you tell me what happened?

Comment: Oh! That actually would be a spoiler. I can only tell that it plays into Willk's answer.

Comment: @Alexander so she turns into an old witch? I have never seen got, but if that's a spoiler, you already spoilered it ;)

Comment: Hint: Why are famous/rich people *in the real world* generally considered better looking, on average, than poor people? (There’s a multitude of reasons, most of which could apply to wizards.)

Comment: Fwiw, you really should go ahead and emend that 'players of their preferred sex' to 'teenaged boys' or 'men'. Women *don't* generally find Schwarzeneggerian men "sexy" in their musculature, although many *other men* do. Women focus more on what RPG fanboys would associate with elven good looks, hence the continuing cult of Legolas even after the implosion of Orlando Bloom's acting career.

Comment: I have seen many sexy witches, but "sexy and muscular" male wizards are more of a meme for certain RPG character builds. Traditionally, male wizards have been these lanky types with gigantic beards, rather than magic missile shooting Schwarzeneggers. Could someone care to provide examples of muscular wizards?

Comment: If you had the ability to use magic to make yourself look more attractive, would you _really_ not use it?

Comment: @lly: I can readily imagine not finding the extremely bulked-up Mr. Universe bodybuilder type attractive, but would many women think that the other extremes - https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/couch-potato-slob-overweight-man-sitting-623823866?src=QIhGxoW9TkbQDrrOVL4D2g-4-9 ot https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57fa71596b8f5bb7f2b78054/t/58489701197aea132bdae945/1481152259479/pc+gaming.jpg?format=500w - are attractive?  And as a practical matter, in a wizard duel, they're likely toast anyway :-)

Comment: 14 year old boys are the main consumers of the genre? And let's be honest, we men are never really more than 14 years old... :-D

Comment: @forest Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality show how a story can go completely sideways when you apply human nature so sensibly, though.

Comment: The usual reasons, I suppose - a combination of genetics, eating right, working out, and magicking away the caloric content of the food they consume.

Answer (score 163):

**Glamour is the first spell they learn!**

In real life, wizards all look like you would expect - skinny spindly bookish guys, chubby balding bookish guys, unkempt old dudes etc.  The first thing they do when they get some magic is get glamoured up, buff and Harlequin romance ready!

If you are familiar with the internet, you will understand that the hot sexy female wizards are also actually one of the male types described above.

Comment: Omg! Putting back your glamour after a night of passion would be the main priority. Otherwise the breakfast will be akward.

Comment: Witcher Series' witches do this. Also in mainstream folklore Hags are famous for this.

Comment: Does the 2nd paragraph imply that all the attractive female wizards are transexual?

Comment: @Philipp It's a joke based on the idea that a lot of women online are actually men, pretending to be women to get something out of gullible guys.

Comment: @Theik: Or in MMO / RPG games like World of Warcraft, guys who play a female avatar because they like looking at a slinky female elf/human/dwarf?/tauren??/... avatar in the middle of their screen for hours, instead of a buff male animated character.  Not usually to trick other people.  Some of my alts were female characters just for variety.  I'm not super into the RP aspect, but I did enjoy imagining my characters existing as a (fictional) character, so I named them plausible in-world names rather than like "noobkiller".

Comment: Some women on Internet use male avatars as the simplest way to avoid sexism/being mistaken for men using a female avatar. The same could be true for those wizards.

Comment: So... in real life wizards are all men, including the ones who look like women? That seems pretty exclusionary, and unnecessary given that your core answer is "glamour is a spell". (Of course it does appear that the OP is asking about male-focused universes...)

Comment: @Cascabel It was also a pretty obvious joke to anyone who's played any MMORPG, as has been explained in the comments before yours. (And no, two people missing it does not mean it's non-obvious, it means that two people out of at least 90 didn't have the cultural context.)

Comment: @NicHartley I get the joke, thank you. I'm just suggesting that the fact that the entire answer ends up having no female wizards is still not great.

Comment: @Theik It's an exclusionary joke, one that's possibly even offensive. I had people use that exact "rule of internet" to invalidate me. The "joke" doesn't even contribute to the answer. I recommend deleting it.

Comment: Since the OP asks about men and women, the answer fails to cover 50% of the spectrum (taste consideration apart)

Comment: @aloisdg: I have to re-read The Witcher books at some point, but if I recall correctly they physically alter themselves?

Comment: NSFW, but related view on the subject: https://www.oglaf.com/cornwalling/

Comment: @Michael Yes. Even more, almost all sorceress start as ugly, as the pretty girls have other career options (like marriage). Yennefer had a hunchback.

Comment: In the Witcher, most sorcerers and sorceresses actually change their looks to keep looking young and beautiful.

Answer (score 82):

#### Breeding

One potential mechanism, cribbed shamelessly from [El Goonish Shive](http://www.egscomics.com/index.php?id=1455) is pretty straightforward:

Magic is intelligent and has ideas of its own, and it wants to be used.  In people with sufficient aptitude, it is so concentrated that it can affect their physiology.

Magic is interested in making more people with magical aptitude, so it can be used more.  It therefore guides the development of people with that aptitude to make them as sexually appealing as possible in an effort to encourage their successful procreation.

Wizards of either sex, therefore, have exaggerated secondary sexual characteristics and an appealing body fat ratio without having to work for it, because magic *wants* them to be good breeding stock.

Comment: +1 for using the concept from EGS.

Comment: _If_ magic is genetically transmitted (plausible) _and_ it confers a selective advantage (highly probable), then [natural selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_selection) explains it is selected for. Sexual attractiveness is (obviously) also selected for. The two factors combine to give sexually-attractive magically-adept individuals the highest reproductive success. (However, just that would imply that the proportion of such individuals grows to the exclusion of others...)

Comment: @PabloH - If natural selection were sufficient pressure to make the population sexier, everyone would be sexy.  I'm arguing unnatural selection (breeding), where magic is giving its own chosen individuals an additional edge.  Particularly since in human society, selection pressures tend to be different than in populations subject to predation.

Comment: @jdunlop If evolutionary pressure, whether due to general natural selection, the more specific [sexual selection](), or artificial selection guided by the Will of Magic, led to everyone getting sexier, then their standards for what constitutes "sexy" would increase. Happens all the time with birds- that's no small part of why so many male birds are so colorful.

Comment: Whoops, I totally forgot to actually put in that link there. Actual sexual selection link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_selection

Answer (score 32):

**Disguise**

We have all the stereotype that a wizard has a long white beard and a pointy hat, and maybe a pair of glasses, while a witch will be a not so nice looking woman, dressed in a black robe and with messy hair.

Now, imagine you are walking in a forest and you see a gentleman with a long white beard and pointy hat coming in your direction: you think he is a mage and evaluate your chances of successfully defending yourself should a fight arise.

Imagine now that you see a medieval version of Pam Anderson running (with all the bouncing) in your direction: will it inspire you fear or something else?

To sum up: in a world where everybody is a potential menace, disguising your true potential and skills is a valuable skill. Mages are known to be dangerous at distance, so having a chance to get close to a potential target is also a valuable tactical advantage.

Comment: This answer actually makes a lot more sense, thanks

Answer (score 18):

**Attracting new practicioners.**

Does every basketball player achieve Jordan's success?
Do you expect Ronaldo's luck with X brand shaving razor?

It sells, so if the Grand Maestre tells you to pick some members for the next fair, you ditch the fat enchanter. No one will join the Alchemist's club if the gal on the stand has pimples and nails-on-chalkboard voice.

Pick a sucessfull Spellweaver who has looks and brain, with a passion for the arcane. Then your next year the kids will beg to enroll.
More students = more money from the crown.

If it brings more money, why not?

Comment: +1, Its just a shame to think this is what would happen in real life... but just to be clear, are you saying i don't have Ronaldo's luck because i have a beard?

Comment: Eurgh. I can just see the celebrity endorsements for magical potions now. *Cinematic shot of a horse on a beach, cut to cinematic shot of famous wizard casting a spell, cut back to beach-horse, then a spray of something, then a rose, then show bottle of healing potion with the strap line ‘Merlin and Morgana: Temptation’*

Comment: @BladeWraith: This is something that usually occurs and works for -not so smart- crowd and to sell unneeded stuff. But here we are talking about the astonishing mage guild, and i guess that the M.I.T. doesen't really need to send sexy people in faires to lure subscribers, they have a really difficult entry test instead!

Comment: @theGarz, although not stated i admit, but i was referring to university funding practices more than anything. which i'm sure even MIT is not innocent of, they get the best and brightest to go to fundraisers and speak to donors, the best and brightest includes people valued for their keen insight and skill and brains. but also often people valued because they put a "good face for it..."

Comment: @theGarz It does work in real life. I have seen men choosing specific careers just because they seemed to attract the most women to college. Not to mention brighter people who are already interested in that career may be more eager to pursue that degree if it comes with perks, namely being surrounded by bombastic people and not greasy-looking smelly nerds.

Comment: @HorriblePerson, are you a horse? :D This kind of men (why are we talking only about men btw?) should follow another career like bards, warriors and so on... It's a long way to become wizard and therefore you have to have strong motivation and dedication. Only after years and years, and only if you succed, you'll have the chanche to modify your appearance. You can choose to be -lets say- a bartender for this reason, but you won't choose to be an astronaut (pretend it's sexy). To summarize, what you wrote could be true for some people but imho it won't apply to the usual sorcerer's apprentice.

Answer (score 16):

**Practicing magic is a strenuous exercise.**

Magic is a powerful force. Summoning and guiding it via gestures is a physical exercise. Learning spells in the library is not all there is to being a wizard.

<sub>Nearly every Manga uses this to explain the protagonists' hulking bodies.</sub>

**Being able to control magic is used for selfish means.**

Who wouldn't optimize their body in terms of physical appearance, simply if they *could*?

Comment: In _Sex, Drugs, and Cocoa Puffs_, Chuck Klosterman poses the hypothetical: imagine you encounter a real magician who offers to make you more attractive for \$; more \$ = more attractive. But the magician will only do this for you once, so you must decide _now_ how much to spend. Klosterman asks: how much would you spend?

Answer (score 14):

## Sex magic

Seriously. Pick all the forms of magic in the real world and at some point they delve into it. Some are all about it.

One of the most known group of practicioners of magic on Earth is the Order Templi Orientis, made famous by Aleister Crowley. Those guys organize their knowledge in degrees, and the higher ones are all about sex magic. They consider masturbatory magic to be the lower form of sex magic, with intercourse based rituals being higher in nature. And you need to be well versed in it these techniques in order to make it to the top of their hierarchy.

In a world where magic is a thing and you get power by doing it like mammals do in the Discovery Channel, a sexy body is a tool to obtain ever more power.

Comment: So do they enchant themselves to look like an Adonis/Aphrodite or do they work out to get that kind of body?

Comment: @MeijiMarts whatever works for them.

Comment: I'd sleep better if I think if these Wizards really worked for that body

Comment: @MeijiMarts, i think part of it could be the concept that they don't, the magic makes other non magical people think that they have Adonis/Aphrodite type bodies, which could be an interesting direction to take, which to be fair, the most attractive users have worked really hard on mastering the spells, so they have technically worked for it... just in a library instead of a gym

Comment: Sounds lazy though..

Answer (score 13):

Isn't that obvious?

I always marvel at wizards in games, including roleplaying and LARP. They all don't seem to think like real people. Because when you learn something new, you don't change your personality, do you? When you learn a new craft or language or anything, does it change what you want in life? Maybe a little, but not fundamentally.

IMHO some of the first things that anyone who more or less suddenly finds himself in possession of magic powers would do is - the same things he would do without, just with magic:

- food
- shelter
- mating

The first thing you do, especially in a medieval/fantasy world where hunger is a real thing and most people know how it is to go a day or two without food, is to check how you can use magic to make sure you are never hungry again.

The second thing would be to ensure you have a proper roof over your head, preferably with a heat source. Magic flame? Favorite spell!

And as soon as you are comfortable and safe, of course your mind turns to "how can I use this new thing to attract members of the opposite sex?". Healing spells, especially if they can restore your teeth, skin, etc. definitely rate high on that scale. If there are spells to shape your body, you will **definitely** use them. The good food and warm shelter from the first steps also helps to get and/or maintain a good body.

These things are what biologists call *fitness indicators* and if you can prop them up by magic, you will. Especially if you are a young adult under the influence of hormones.

Answer (score 11):

Who wants to live forever? Wizards, of course.

The only issue is that they have to spend most of their time studying and practicing magic, while other normal people go to the gym and mate other people, but they know that their time will come.

After years and years of dedication they finally master some branches of magic and they can have their payback.
Given that several enchanters can perform a full shapeshift it's not a big deal to modify their own appearance to meet the current beauty standard.

It's not a lazy way, they spent years on their books, and it's way more smart to work out in a library rather than in a gym. A bodybuilder will grow old, a wizard will grow powerfull then, granted intelligence is mandatory to become a wizard, they totally won't spend their time trying to sculpt a mortal, frail, aging body, but they will do their best to increase their power (and therefore their appearance, that can be modified as they wish).

There's actually a downside in this behaviour, and it could be a relevant downside especially where there's a high wizard concentration: a wizard will end up mating another wizard, since only another wizard can match his/her beauty. That's a problem because a wizard will recongnize another one and he/she definitely won't to "create a family" with another wizard, and with their power it would be easy to control their fertility. On the other hand the not-wizard people are not that appealinig, except for few really special people. This actually is the reason why, in the end, wizard are so rare: they can have as many one night stand as they wish but they luckily won't have offspring.

Ps: since a wizard can modify his appearance and he is intelligent, the "Adone" shape will be used in "commercials" and saturday night but, in order to avoid possbile backfire by gealous ex lovers and/or king's discomfort for the wizard's influence on the queen, when they do their "official" business they will use a "Merlin" shape.
They are paid for their wisdom and power, so they are just maximizing their appearance again to have the maximum gain.

Aren't they supposed to be really intelligent after all?

Answer (score 9):

#### They don't have sexy bodies - you just *think* that they have a sexy body

This is similar to the [glamour idea from @Willk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/118688/28789), but different in that they don't have an illusion around them.

Everyone has a certain magical energy and potential in him. This energy is constantly leaking out. Have you ever thought that someone has this kind of *aura* around them? That's not simply their personal attitude, it's more like magical pheromones. The more magic, the stronger the pheromones that tell you: "This person is *sexy*."

Your perception is skewed into *thinking* they are extremely sexy, when in fact they are quite normal, but with an enormous amount of power leaking out of them and telling you that they are exceptional individuals and mating with them would be good for the bloodline, because:

magic = power = survival

Because of [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance) your brain will then proceed to rationalize why you feel that these ordinary looking individuals are so extremely attractive. And the easiest thing is to overlook everything that doesn't align with the typical characteristics or what society defines to be "sexy" for the average non-magical person. This makes you *think* they have sexy bodies when in fact they don't.

This way there is no awkward *morning breakfast* after forgetting to put your glamour back on. It's always on as long as the magical energy is not suppressed by something. But the moment it *is* suppressed the individual will look quite plain compared with the image humans had in mind.

This also makes wizards extremely weird for normal people and might help with the perception of them being *different*. While the general view of biology on what defines "sexy" is ingrained into the minds of people there are differences that are defined by society and "sexy" can also differ from individual to individual - which means that different people might desribe wizards slightly different. Simplified: one group of people talks about the upper body, while the rest talks about the lower body of the individual wizard. This leads to people not being able to properly describe the wizard and therefore leads to a *aura of mystery* around these individuals, which increases "traditional sexiness" yet again. They are rare and complicated individuals and nobody is *completely* sure what they look like, but everyone knows they are extremely *sexy* - whatever you think *sexy* means.

Comment: I really like this.  As much as I think that Willk's answer could really happen, this makes even more sense.

Answer (score 7):

**Mens sana in corpore sano**

The manta of wizardry is *mens sana in corpore sano*: the younger wizards wish the attract a partner, the older ones wish to stay alive, all have a direct incentive to stay healthy.

Therefore, the first interesting spells studied by wizards, straight out of basics (aka small telekinesis, dust cleaning, ...), are basic body reinforcement spells:

- disease purification,
- poison purification,
- healing,
- fat control,
- ...

Masters know it's important, and know their young students are keen to learn it, so they teach it first and use it to convey the fundamental concepts of magic.

As a result, all wizards just know how to maintain a healthy body.

Actually, an unhealthy body is a mark of insanity for wizards, and history has proven that those wizards who let their bodies degenerate soon devolve into villains.

Answer (score 6):

**Inherent "Healing" Ability**

Magic is good for the body, and promotes health and well-being in practitioners of both sexes. Minor ailments tend to pass them by, and even major issues will heal completely given time. It could even help them maintain a healthy weight and muscle tone despite lack of exercise.

So while they mightn't be super attractive, they do tend to have clear skin, good hair and teeth, be fairly fit and have that air of confidence that comes so naturally to magic-users.

Answer (score 6):

Magic is sexy!

If you're only interested in out-of-world opinions, then the definition of "sexy" comes from our culture, and will need to be tailored to our particular concept of "sexy."  However, if you think in-world, if magic is something desirable, any body characteristics or behaviors associated with magic will develop an element of sexyness to them as they become desirable in-world.  Whatever magicians have, the opposite sex will want.

Related: reading is sexy
[image: Reading is sexy]

Answer (score 6):

Two reasons, somewhat related.

First, wizardry takes energy, some of which (the part that controls the rest) has to come from the wizard's own body.  Thus, the more physically fit the wizard is, the easier it is to control magic, and the more powerful the level of magic the wizard can control.  So a successful wizard pretty well HAS to be pretty muscular.

You might, for instance, think of doing a magic spell as rather like push-starting a car. (Something that those of us who've owned '60s British sports cars¹ are all too familiar with.)

Second, part of wizardry involves heightened control over one's own body.  One can heal diseases, and within limits shape one's body into a desired form.  So while it isn't as simple as waving one's magic wand about, wizardry augments the effects of exercise, so that the wizard gets a buff body with much less gym time than normal folks.

PS: WRT female wizards and big boobs², a lot of it is development of the pectoral muscles and the contrast with a trim, muscular waistline, e.g. https://woman.thenest.com/can-strengthening-chest-muscles-increase-breast-size-7762.html

¹All hail Lucas, Lord of Darkness!

²It should be noted that not all of us think big boobs are really that sexy.  Too much association with Holsteins https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/Cow_female_black_white.jpg/220px-Cow_female_black_white.jpg at an impressionable age, I suppose.

Comment: Your first point can't really explain how could be a demilich one of the most powerful wizard, since he's actually nothing more than a skull or a hand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demilich_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons) But i guess that it could be explained considering that it were a human necromancer, and necromancers tend to have some weird ideas about how to power a body...

Comment: @theGarz: Other people's ideas of magic, particularly as expressed in computer games, are simply myth :-)

Comment: @theGarz  Alternatively the demilich has become less like a creature and more like a magic item.

Comment: @Perkins the demi lich isn't an item at all, it's the last level for a necromancer. While is questionable to address it as a human, and therefore a "simple" wizard, it can't be seen as an item.

Comment: @theGarz: But I think you missed my point, which is that the way "magic" is supposed to work in the mythos of that computer game is not necessarily the way magic works in the OP's world, or in mine :-)

Comment: @theGarz in the universe of D&D, yes.  However, in that universe powerful magic users aren't universally attractive either.  A demilich being closer to a sentient magic item than a "normal" spellcaster is an explanation that would explain its ability to violate the "spellcasters are beautiful" rule in the universe described by the asker.

Comment: @theGarz: Also, necromancers work differently than normal wizards.  Instead of using their own power to cast spells, they use the power that comes from killing things or digging up dead bodies.  So necromancy is probably not for the would-be magician who's squeamish and/or doesn't care to become a social outcast (as necromancers tend to be).

Answer (score 6):

Look at The Witcher world, in this world sorceresses look hot while Wizards usually look old and frail even if they are young, they can change their bodies with permanent enchantments and they do it because their clients expects them to be hot for women and old and fragile for men, also the sorceresses tradition usually favors having ugly apprentices so they work hard to master magic so they can change their appearance so they can stop being mocked by others.

Also after someone masters magic they lose their means of reproduction so they can fool around all they want without consecuences (also they are unable to catch STD) so being hotter is even better for them.

And for wizards not all of them look old, one of the books antagonist is a wizard that looks young and is quite muscular, to the point that it can go 1 on 1 with the protagonist (who is mutant that hunts monsters) without any problem.

So maybe the reason in your world both wizards and sorceresses look like super models or porn actresses is because people have that precognition that the best wizards and sorceresses should be hot because the magic to change your own body is hard to master so if one can change its own body means that are truly masters and not lowly apprentices.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *draconk*! Interesting answer and good example of this being used in existing fiction. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 5):

The simple evolution of magic.

The most basic needs for humans are food, shelter and sex. Shelter could be anything from finding a dry and out of the wind spot to sleep to making fires to making cloths to building entire houses, and food&sex are similarily large.

Why they would look good:

- Better food and shelter means indirectly better physical appearance
- Having access to magically superior food and shelter will make you more wanted as a mate
- Magically improving your physical body has multiple advantages: it helps you survive more, gather more food and build better shelters, helps you recover from dibilitating/ugly wounds and makes you look sexier to the others as you are better adapted to the environment.
- As slightly metioned in the previous point, physical body manipulation can be used to heal yourself and others.
- another advantage is that you can improve others around you, such as the mate you've chosen or you can help your children be strong, smart and sexy for their futures.

Magical manipulation of your physical body would have the most reasons for mages to pursue, so it's likely that if magic were real, physical body magic would be the largest field.

Answer (score 4):

### There are two types of wizards - fit ones and dead ones

(aka the Rincewind/Harry Dresden style of wizardry)

To the general populous, a wizard is a being of unimaginable power.  But in the grand scheme of things, wizards are actually fairly low on the totem pole of magical beings.  They have just enough power to be attractive as batteries, but not enough to defend themselves from the more powerful beings who want to use them as such.  So wizards become very good at running away.

And even the average, everyday wizard has got nothing on the research wizards who work in labs.  When a chemist says "Oops", everyone with sense ducks behind a desk.  When a wizard says "Oops", anyone who's still in the room 5 seconds later is a fool.  And the really smart ones have cleared the building.

I can't explain the big bosoms, though.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps its just that they are **hot and sexy** compared the your typical common dirt farmer.

A wizard who knows to cast a spell to purify his drinking water will be worlds more healthy than one who gets theirs from the sewage and parasite infused runoff of the local stream.  Commoners might get scarred from the many diseases and poxes they face.  For wizards such ailments are unknown.  For dirt farmers, toiling under the sun has brutal consequences on their skin, making it cracked and leathery.  Wizards stay cool in the shade and have marvelous skin.  Ever see the feet of a commoner?  All calloused and gross from working the fields with primitive footwear.  Wizards have nice sandals and boots.  Scraggly and knotted hair?  A simple spell will solve that.  Mud stains (or worse) on your old clothes?  Even an apprentice can keep their colorful silk ropes in top condition.  Breasts need a boost... this old concoction the elves told you about will do the trick.  And lets not forget bad breadth - a quick wave of the finger and the wizard's breath is now minty fresh.

Answer (score 3):

Witches and wizards are extremely motivated individuals. They have to be or they wouldn't be any good at magic, because learning magic takes not only great intelligence and memory, but extreme dedication.

Most magicians' desires don't end with mastering magic. These narcissists are obsessed with proving their perfection and superiority over weaker people in all ways. Part of this obsession obviously includes obtaining physical superiority. And they are in luck; compared with mastering magic, getting fit is *dead easy*. All they have to do is regularly eat well and exercise, a small task next to the exhausting strain that is practicing magic.

Comment: True, as what I see in magic, it requires determination and patience on the practitioner, it's hard to search and experiment on magic, but pretty easy to learn how to stay fit

Comment: I was about to answer something similar. Wizards need discipline. Healthy eating takes planning, not time; a little exercise doesn't take much time at all. it's not like top chess players would be enormously fat; this logic actually works IRL.

Answer (score 3):

I think Andrzej Sapkowski of Witcher fame gives one of the best explanations to this. They were not like that, female wizards were generally raised from noble lines. These noble lines found better use for their great looking women. Wizardy didn't improve the nobles situation because they were generally removed from the noble lineage creating their own (or terminating it as it were).

So mostly the women chosen for wizardy were in fact ugly. Since this was such a big stigma on the person chosen, more often than not one of the first thing they would do is to improve the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Genetic correlation.

I recall hearing once a theory that the reason different dog breeds have such similar facial structures to each other compared to their shared canine ancestral stock was that they were bred for domestication, and the same genes for that facial structure were involved in tractability. The appearance (or that aspect of it) just sort of came along for the ride.

It just so happens that some of the same genes that control attractiveness (e.g. waist-to-hip ratio for women, chest-to-waist ration for men) are also related to magical ability.

Answer (score 1):

The body needs to be fit to withstand the damage magic may caused, be it from other magicians or their own magic.
Some magic systems even include martial arts.
If they are supposed to fight against other people they need to be in their best shape.
Most magicians also have access to healing magic which can keep their body in good condition.
In most settings magic itself alters and enhances bodies of creatures that are infused with it or surrounded by it.
That is one of the reasons for their longevity too.

Answer (score 0):

In "The wheel of time" universe, magic is achieved by channeling an invisible force, not unlike "The Force" in Star Wars. One of the side effects of channeling is that it slows down ageing.

Similarly, you can say that magic has rejuvenating properties - the more more you do it, the fitter and better looking you become.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good answers, but one that nobody else seems to have gotten to yet: magic runs in families, and magicians have been able to find attractive mates for millennia.  Therefore, they all have the genes of their attractive ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

#### Evolution of sex appeal over physical survival traits

(Note: Only works for "magical races")

Most species evolve primarily for survival-related traits related to finding food or escaping/fighting off predators - strength, speed, durability, and so forth.  In species where life is easy, where food is plentiful and there are no natural predators, sexual selection becomes much more prominent - which is why many island birds (for example) have exaggerated sexual traits, whether visual (the tails of birds of paradise) or otherwise (the impressive booming calls of the kakapo).

There is actually some (controversial) evidence that this has occurred in humans; our appearance has become more neotenous (child-like) since prehistoric times, and there are some theories that this is because as we relied less and less on our bodies for survival our sex appeal increased.  This may be increasing further since the industrial revolution, though it is still too early to tell.  While there is some overlap between physical fitness and sex appeal in humans, it is not quite as direct as many people believe; athletes (especially lifters) do not look like models, and fitness doesn't have a huge effect on the face in any event.

Wizards, by virtue of their magic, rely far less on being good at doing stuff physically than non-wizards (especially in a medieval world where most people do a lot of manual labor).  Breeding among magical races will therefore place a higher emphasis on sexual traits which will leave its mark on the race over time.